# Javascript dynamic array key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic

I have an object and for properties I have name and attributes:

```
var name;
var attributes = new Array();
```

The user is suppose to insert attributes on its own but in order key->value.

So whichever attributes the user inserts, they need to be written inside the array.

Example: color->red, use->optional, etc...

Can someone please help me, how can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the array to ultimately look like?

Comment: I don't find it very clear what you're going for. Can you clarify? What do you mean by "So whichever attributes the user inserts, they need to be written inside the array."? And if you want key/value pairs, should you be using a Map?

Comment: You mention an array and then say you have an object.  Which is it?  It looks like an object might be a better fit for your case.

Comment: javascript do support dictionaries, maybe you can try this : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117002/Javascript-Dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If you get the data from an input field, you can split it first by comma and then each of the newly created array elements by that arrow and use them to construct an Object, like so:

```js
document.querySelector("#i").addEventListener("change", logObject);


function logObject(e) {
  let val = this.value;
  let arr = val.split(", ");
  arr = arr.map(e => e.split("->"));
  let obj = {};
  arr.forEach(e => obj[e[0]] = e[1]);
  console.log(obj)
}
```

```html
<input id="i"> 
<br> color->red, use->optional
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should not implement an array for that, instead you should use an object (map) like this.

```
var attributes = {};
attributes.color = 'red';
attributes.use = 'optional';
```